# html column styling and border css

Tags: html, css, layout, styles

what  i have in the code:
wrapper div outemost which in css i made to width of auto so all the inner divs have to align

inside my container div which inside of wrapper container div contains both sidebars which should be same height. Instead they don't do this and Im not sure why. Instead of having two sidebars I would like to keep the right sidebar and strect the content from the left sidebar from the left to the right sidebar.

Another major problem is that the right sidebar keeps overflowing its text and when i tried overflow:hidden it just hid evrything outside of the sidebar div which isn't what I want

here is jsfiddle so you can better see it. I want to stop overflowing on the right sidebar 
and when the left sidebar is width to touch the right sidebar then under the content of the leftsidebar is where i want the buttons becuase they go out the screen when I widen the width.

http://jsfiddle.net/b6bW4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <html>
        <title>Building Blocks to Html</title>
        <head>
            <SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
                var updated = document.lastModified document.write("Last modified: " + updated)
            </script>
            <script src="start.js"></script>
            <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, Hyper Text Markup Language, />
            <meta name="description" content="HTML in easy steps. Introductory tutorial for beginners." / >
            <meta name="author" content="Miguel Castaneda" />
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="robots" content="all, nofollow" />
            <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
            <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <!--  wrapper holds everything should be auto  -->
                <div id="mod"></div>
                <!-- end of mod -->
                <center>
                    <a name="top"></center>
                    <center>
                        <a href="#bottom">Bottom</a>
                    </center>
                    <div id="mainmenu">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- 5 table spacing links//-->
                            <li>
                                <a href="html.html">HTML</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="python.html">Python</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="widgets.html">Widgets</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of mainmenu  -->
                    <div id="container">
                        //container holds content and sidebar
                        <div id="sidebar">
                            <p>HELLLLLLLLLLLEEEwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwMwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwEwwwwwwawawakdjadjlkajdlk;asmdksm.a</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end of sidebar -->
                        <div id="content">
                            <p >
                                <!-- browser picks first one in array if not in cpu then goes to 2nd font //-->
                                <tt>
                                    Programmer: Miguel Castaneda(iSten23)
                                    <br>
                                </br>
                                Head First HTML5 Programming
                                <br>
                            </br>
                            THIS SITE IS FOR EXPERIMENTAL PURPOSES, IS NOT INTENDED FOR COMMERCIAL PURPOSES.
                        </p>
                    </tt>
                </div>
                <!-- end of content -->
            </div>
            <!--  end of containeer-->
            <center>
                <a  href="#top" id="topl">Top</a>
                <div  id="leftrightB" >
                    <UL id="ul-list">
                        <li>
                            <a  id="rightB"href="basic5.html" class="addborder" >
                                <img    src="arrow1.png" height="40" width="40" alt="Link to next page">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a  id="leftB"href="basic7.html" class="addborder">
                                <img    src="arrow.png" height="40" width="40" alt="Link to next page">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--end of leftrightB  -->
                <div id="footermenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- 5 table spacing links//-->
                        <li>
                            <a href="html.html">HTML</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="python.html">Python</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="widgets.html">Widgets</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- END OF FOOTERMENU -->
                <a name="bottom"></div>
                <!--  END OF WRAPPER-->
            </body>
            <style>
                #ul-list li {
                }
                a:hover {
                    color: #00f000;
                    text-shadow: 0px 2px green;
                }
                .addborder:hover {
                    border: 1px solid #000000;
                }
                #sidebar {
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0;
                    margin-top: 2px;
                    background-color: #8cc63f;
                    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
                    font-size: 10px;
                    line-height: 1;
                    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
                    width: 10%;
                    height: 480px;
                    background-image: radial-gradient(hsla(0, 0%, 87%, 0.31) 9px, transparent 10px), repeating-radial-gradient(hsla(0, 0%, 87%, 0.31) 0, hsla(0, 0%, 87%, 0.31) 4px, transparent 5px, transparent 20px, hsla(0, 0%, 87%, 0.31) 21px, hsla(0, 0%, 87%, 0.31) 25px, transparent 26px, transparent 50px);
                    background-size: 30px 30px, 90px 90px;
                    background-position: 0 0;
                    <!-- //white-space: nowrap;
                    //overflow: hidden;
                    //word-wrap: break-word -->
                }
                #wrapper {
                    width: auto;
                }
                #content {
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 0;
                    background-color: #8cc63f;
                    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
                    font-size: 10px;
                    line-height: 1;
                    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
                    width: 10%;
                    height: 480px;
                }
                <!-- img {
                    border-width: 1px;
                    border-color: Black;
                }
                --> .table {
                    display: table;
                    <!-- Allow the centering to work */ --> margin: 0 auto;
                }
                ul#ul-list {
                    min-width: 696px;
                    list-style: none;
                    padding-top: 20px;
                }
                ul#ul-list li {
                    display: inline;
                }
                #mainmenu {
                    width: auto;
                    height: 35px;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    text-align: center;
                    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
                    background-color: #8AD9FF;
                    border-radius: 8px;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50px;
                    left: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    margin-left: 0;
                    margin-right: 0;
                }
                #mainmenu ul {
                    height: auto;
                    padding: 8px 0px;
                    margin: 0px;
                }
                #mainmenu li {
                    display: inline;
                    padding: 20px;
                }
                #mainmenu a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #00F;
                    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
                }
                #mainmenu a:hover {
                    color: #F90;
                    background-color: #FFF;
                }
                #footermenu {
                    width: auto;
                    height: 35px;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    text-align: center;
                    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
                    background-color: #52D7E5;
                    //main color of the menu border-radius: 8px;
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 0px;
                    left: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    margin-left: 0;
                    margin-right: 0;
                }
                #footermenu ul {
                    height: auto;
                    padding: 8px 0px;
                    margin: 0px;
                }
                #footermenu li {
                    display: inline;
                    padding: 20px;
                }
                #footermenu a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #00F;
                    // padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
                }
                #footermenu a:hover {
                    color: #F90;
                    background-color: #17861A;
                    //color of gover over iterm
                }
                rightleftB {
                    display: table-cell vertical-align: bottom;
                }
                #wrapper {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            </style>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this...

[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/b6bW4/1/)

```
body{

overflow: hidden;

 }
```